# How to add subtitle to video keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I tried to convert a video with aspect ratio 16:9 and want to add subtitles. The final video has black bars (I need it that way for a portable media player). But the subtitles are not shown in the final video. Is there an additional argument to accomplish this? In mencoder this can be done, but there is a problem playing it: it skips some frames. I'll post the line, hoping someone can help me.

`$ ffmpeg -i 'TOS.mp4' -vcodec libxvid -vtag XVID -aspect 4:3 -r 20 -b:v 300k -s 320x240 -vf "subtitles='TOS.srt':force_style='Fontsize=24'" -vf "scale=w=320:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=320:240:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -acodec mp2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ss 00:00:40 -t 00:01:30 TOS-test17.avi`

Answer (score 0):

All video filters should be defined in a single chain.

```
ffmpeg -i 'TOS.mp4'
    -vf "subtitles='TOS.srt':force_style='Fontsize=24',
         scale=w=320:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,
         pad=320:240:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"
    -r 20 -aspect 4:3 -vcodec libxvid -b:v 300k -vtag XVID
    -acodec mp2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 TOS.avi
```

Comment: It worked. Is it possible to set the subtitles in the down black bar area?and, is there a limit for the Fontsize?